# IDA pro dump memory snapshot to file

Tags: ida, memory-dump

My question is rather simple, I was analysing a piece of malware packed by some packer in IDA. I have found a memory mapped (via mmap2) region which contains the file I'm interested in. I've created a memory snapshot and I'd like to copy this specific area into a file.

Sadly I haven't been able to find good instructions on how to do this, any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be helpful: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/ida-pro-export-c-style-array-using-python-instead-of-gui-menu/14593#14593
Only you should save that as binary instead of hex values. I'm only suggesting this because IDA's not that good at exporting EXEs. You may also want to try ollydbg with a dumping plugin.